# How to get latest folder path from S3 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have multiple s3 file paths which contain the folder name as date. I want to extract the latest path from S3 using python and boto3 based on the date.

For Example- Below are the few paths I have under my root folder(s3:///all/stage/servicenow/service-mgmt/sm_task/raw/)
Sample Paths -

1. s3://my-bucket/all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/2020/12/11/10/20/file.parquet
2. s3://my-bucket/all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/2020/12/11/11/12/file.parquet
3. s3://my-bucket/all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/2020/12/11/12/01/file.parquet
4. s3://my-bucket/all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/2020/12/12/11/10/file.parquet

all the above paths are in s3:///all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/file.parquet format

So I need the latest timestamp path under root path (s3:///all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/) which is s3:///all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/2020/12/12/11/10/file.parquet.

How can i achieve this using python and Boto3.

Any help will be appreciated as I am new in python

Please comment if the question is not clear

Comment: If you list the objects with a Prefix specified, then the "latest" one will be the **last one in the list**. You would call `list_objects(Prefix='all/stage/pqr/xyz/abc/raw/')` and then obtain the last result within your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import path
```

is one way to check the file
using function

```
os.path.splitext(root,date)
```

and just use your own algorithm to check weather or not your file time is the newest

Comment: Here I don't know the latest date So what should I provide under os.path.splitext(root,date)...

Comment: just add an if function to check if the file is the newest. First check your year then month and so on if there is a file that has a newer time check that file again. I think that will slove your problem